# Why does 'jobs' return pid that already terminated?

Tags: bash

I'm playing with job management in bash, and am seeing confusing behavior.

Here is a minimal script to demonstrate:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

function start_job {
    echo "Kicking off job that sleeps for ${1}"
    sleep "${1}" && echo "Slept for ${1}!" &
}

# Start some jobs - print current child pids.
echo "Jobs are: $(jobs -p)"
start_job 5
echo "Jobs are: $(jobs -p)"
start_job 6
echo "Jobs are: $(jobs -p)"
start_job 7
echo "Jobs are: $(jobs -p)"

# Wait long enough for all children to finish.
echo "Main thread sleeping for 10 and killing all remaining jobs."
sleep 10
echo "Killing sub-jobs."
echo "Jobs are: $(jobs -p)"
kill $(jobs -p)
```

We create a bunch of child jobs (sleep and report back).

Then we wait for all them them to have a chance to terminate.

Then we invoke `jobs -p` and kill any pid it returns.

If I change things so my last sleep is 5 seconds, it correctly identifies the 2 remaining pids and kills them.

But if I run it as-is (sleep until they ALL finish), I get the following output:

```
Jobs are: 
Kicking off job that sleeps for 5
Jobs are: 3352412
Kicking off job that sleeps for 6
Jobs are: 3352412
3352415
Kicking off job that sleeps for 7
Jobs are: 3352412
3352415
3352418
Main thread sleeping for 10 and killing all remaining jobs.
Slept for 5!
Slept for 6!
Slept for 7!
Killing sub-jobs.
Jobs are: 3352418
./mini_job_test.sh: line 23: kill: (3352418) - No such process
```

This seems totally broken. That `3352418` corresponds to the `Slept for 7` job, which, as `kill` correctly reports back, is a pid that doesn't exist. What gives?

EDIT

Looks like I can specify -r for running jobs and -s for stopped jobs, and with -r, it seems to behave.

... but then I'd expect the funky pid to be stopped... but if I do -s, then that doesn't show up... so:

- jobs -p: returns that last pid
- jobs -pr: returns no pids
- jobs -ps: returns no pids <-- shouldn't it at least show up here if jobs -p is returning a non-running pid???

Comment: Added an edit to talk about -s and -r, which still behave surprisingly in this context.

Comment: Use `wait` for waiting for jobs.

Comment: The actual usecase I'm working towards spins up some continuous monitoring jobs and kills them when the main processing foreground task terminates, so I don't think this is a `wait` situation.

Comment: `jobs -ps` doesn't show anything because `Stopped` means *paused* (can be done by pressing ctrl+z on a foreground job in an interactive terminal). Completed jobs are called `Done`. See the [documentation of `<state>` in posix](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/jobs.html).